# Linux / Debian - set default route to wifi

Tags: linux, networking, debian

I am trying to delete the default eth0 route in order to give the default route to wlan0 (wifi). I have added the following in

`/etc/network/interfaces.d/`

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0
        allow-hotplug eth0
        iface eth0 inet dhcp
        up route del default`

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces.d/wlan0
        auto wlan0
        iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid "XXXX"
        wpa-psk xxxxx
        up route add default gw 192.168.1.1 netmask 0.0.0.0`

But when i reboot & do 'route -n', I get

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0`

Which is clearly not what i want...

I am starting to become crazy, can someone explain to me why my configuration is not working ?!

Answer (score 0):

DHCP will set your default route(s), and that may well happen after the scripts for `up` are executed. So don't try to deal with a race condition (inserting sleep etc.), instead configure `dhclient` in `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` to `supersede` the `routers` value for `eth0`.

(Haven't done this myself, but that's what I'd try first.)

Comment: I tried adding `interface "eth0" {

        supersede routers 0.0.0.0;

}` but to no effect...

Answer (score 0):

It seems i found the answer:

I just had to add 

`interface eth0
nogateway`

in /etc/dhcpcd.conf